# Collect id's of ALL inserted records as result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need a stored procedure which returns resultset of IDs for created records. I've already read that SCOPE_IDENTITY gives only last ID. but my SQL skill is not enough to solve this particular case and get all IDs as the output.

here's what I have for now - this only gets the last record's id

```
USE AdventureWorks2008;
DELETE FROM [HumanResources].[Shift] where [HumanResources].[Shift].Name='c' or [HumanResources].[Shift].Name='d'
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'ShiftUpdateXml')
DROP PROCEDURE ShiftUpdateXml
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE ShiftUpdateXml
 @strXML XML, @ShiftID [tinyint] = NULL OUTPUT  
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    INSERT [HumanResources].[Shift](Name,StartTime,EndTime) SELECT 
    TEMP.Name,TEMP.StartTime,TEMP.EndTime
        FROM (SELECT 
    assignreassignro.value('Name[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS Name,
    assignreassignro.value('StartTime[1]','time(7)') AS StartTime,
    assignreassignro.value('EndTime[1]','time(7)') AS EndTime

    FROM @strXML.nodes('documentelement/assignreassignro')Documentelement(assignreassignro)) AS TEMP

    SET @ShiftID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
GO

DECLARE @ShiftID INT;
DECLARE @XmlVal XML= '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<documentelement>
  <assignreassignro>
    <Name>c</Name>
    <StartTime>10:30:00.0000000</StartTime>
    <EndTime>17:30:00.0000000</EndTime>
  </assignreassignro>
  <assignreassignro>
     <Name>d</Name>
    <StartTime>11:00:00.0000000</StartTime>
    <EndTime>18:00:00.0000000</EndTime>
  </assignreassignro>
</documentelement>'

EXEC  ShiftUpdateXml @XmlVal,@ShiftID = @ShiftID OUTPUT;
PRINT @ShiftID;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `output` clause.  If you just want the ids, you can do:

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE (id int);

INSERT [HumanResources].[Shift](Name,StartTime,EndTime)
    OUTPUT inserted.Id INTO @ids
    SELECT assignreassignro.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Name,
           assignreassignro.value('StartTime[1]', 'time(7)') AS StartTime,
           assignreassignro.value('EndTime[1]', 'time(7)') AS EndTime
    FROM @strXML.nodes('documentelement/assignreassignro') Documentelement(assignreassignro);
```

If you want additional values, you can add them to the table and the `INSERT` statement.

Also, note that you do not need a subquery for the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

To get multiple rows you'll need to use output from the table inserted with something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ShiftUpdateXml
 @strXML XML 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT [Shift](Name,StartTime,EndTime) 
    output inserted.id
    SELECT 
    TEMP.Name,TEMP.StartTime,TEMP.EndTime
        FROM (SELECT 
    assignreassignro.value('Name[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS Name,
    assignreassignro.value('StartTime[1]','time(7)') AS StartTime,
    assignreassignro.value('EndTime[1]','time(7)') AS EndTime

    FROM @strXML.nodes('documentelement/assignreassignro')Documentelement(assignreassignro)) AS TEMP
END
```

That way the procedure will return the list of IDs. I made an example into [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59bf6/2)